# AngularJS - select option and use it in a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a cshtml file in which i have following code (a dropdown with data taken from a model)

```
<div class="controls">
  <select ng-model="model.CountryCode" ng-change="countryChanged({{country.ISO316613LetterCode}})">
    <option ng-repeat="country in model.Countries" value="{{country.ISO316613LetterCode}}">{{country.CommonName}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And i have this function, in which i detect that a country was chosen from the dropdown

```
    $scope.countryChanged = function(){
        var countryDet = _.find($scope.model.CountryDetails, function(cd){
            console.log("countryDet");
            return cd.CountryCode === $scope.model.Country;
        });

        if(countryDet){
            $scope.model.CountryDetail = countryDet;

            // set business properties from country details
            $scope.model.DateFormat = countryDet.DefaultDateFormat;
            $scope.model.ShortDateFormat = countryDet.DefaultShortDateFormat;
            $scope.model.DateFormatJs = countryDet.DefaultJsDateFormat;
            $scope.model.LongDateFormat = countryDet.DefaultLongDateFormat;
            $scope.model.TaxCode = countryDet.SalesTaxName;
            $scope.model.Currency = countryDet.DefaultCurrencySign;
            $scope.model.AccSoftwareDateFormat = countryDet.DefaultAccSoftwareDateFormat
            $scope.model.WeightSystem = countryDet.DefaultWeightSystem
        }

        $scope.loadStates();
    };
```

And another function, that should display additional dropdown on web, showing states if the country choosen was USA or AUstralia

```
    $scope.stateVisible = function(){

        if($scope.model && $scope.model.CountryDetail){
          return $scope.model.CountryDetail.StateVisible;
        }

        return false;
    };
```

My problem is, that i do not know how to send the selected LetterCode (value of option) to function countryChanged, because, i thought if i do so, then i will be able to easilly load the states into the additional dropdown and show it on site.

Comment: So you want to add a states dropdown dynamically to your page when user selects a country right?

Comment: you should try ng repeat with key and value with ng-options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `ng-options` which will assign the selected model to the `ng-model` for the `<select>`. For example

```
<select ng-model="model.selectedCountry" ng-change="countryChanged()"
    ng-options="country.CommonName for country in model.Countries track by country.ISO316613LetterCode">
</select>
```

Then, your `countryChanged()` function (and any other controller function) can use `$scope.model.selectedCountry` which will be a full *country* object.

Plunker demo ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/tFjvT92B1itmwkRjZIbJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using $scope for every variable you could use rootScope

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope

for passing the data.